# Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler previous versions

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

Where can I find old versions of Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler x64 (4.1.1)?

In Oracle site there is the current version 23.1 and I cannot find a links to previous versions.

I need a direct link to download that old version for education.